# Is there a way to play multiplayer on MK11?

Tags: mortal-kombat-11

For example, could I play Co-Op on Mk11? Let's say my friend and I wanted to play together on one console with many controllers. Could we work together on a tag team or something? If there is how do we do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to different sources:

> In the *Fight* menu, you’ll be able to directly select a “Local” option for local multiplayer. After that, simply ensure your friend has a controller that’s set up and ready to go. In addition to casual fighters through the “Local” co-op setting, there’s a “Tournament” option available for local co-op that ups the ante if you and your friend wish to be a bit more competitive with one another.

So no, there's no tag team to work together apparently.

<sub>Sources: [Twinfinite](https://twinfinite.net/2019/04/mortal-kombat-11-local-online-multiplayer-how-play/), [Ocenaup](https://oceanup.com/28287/how-to-play-mortal-kombat-11/), [Hyperxgaming](https://ag.hyperxgaming.com/article/7417/is-there-local-co-op-in-mortal-kombat-11).</sub>